# How to access user location manually if the user denies location permission in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, mkmapview

I want to access the user location of the user even if the user has denied the permission .how to get the user location if its manually.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    determineMyCurrentLocation()
}

func determineMyCurrentLocation() {
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    if status == .authorizedWhenInUse || status == .authorizedAlways       {
```

locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
 }

```
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
   let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.20, longitudeDelta: 0.20))
         print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("error::: \(error)")

}
```

Comment: If the user denies permission, then you can't access their location. If you could use their location anyway, what would be the point of a permission system?

Comment: can we get the location coordinates manually in that case?What will the map show if the user denies permission?

Comment: What location coordinates? - The user's current location?  No. You can't get location without permission.  The map won't show the user's location.  It will show a default region; I think the whole country as determined by the device's region setting.

Comment: ok is it possible to get the coordinates manually when the permission is denied?

Comment: What location coordinates? - The user's current location? No. You can ask the user to tap on the map where they are, but you have no way of knowing if they are telling the truth.

Comment: i mean some way to ask user to type in latitude and longitude?

Comment: Sure. You could ask them, but they probably won't know their latitude and longitude

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193884/discussion-between-saranya-and-paulw11).